# How can I check which mobile frequencies my phone supports?

Tags: 3g

I received a Samsung Galaxy Nexus as a present (in Australia), however I'm not sure where it came from so I'm not sure what mobile frequency bands it supports. Is there a way to check which frequencies it supports so I know which mobile networks I should be looking at?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find out which bands my phone supports](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/78974/how-can-i-find-out-which-bands-my-phone-supports)

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org/) and the [XDA-Developers Wiki](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) should be a good resource:

- [GT-I9250 on XDA Wiki](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Nexus/GT-I9250)
- [GT-I9250 on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_Nexus)

Comment: I had a look at that but I noticed under LTE it mentions "region specific" so I'm wondering is there's a way to check this as I presume it may depend on the country or even the carrier the phone was released under.

Comment: There are actually two versions of this phone: Galaxy Nexus and Galaxy Nexus LTE. I think the LTE device is available only in North America so far.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is such option in Android, but if you know your phone's model you could always google it. For instance, if you look at [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_Nexus) about Galaxy Nexus, you would see that it supports all four GSM bandwidths (850/900/1800/1900).

Just have a look at "Compatible networks" section in the box on right side.

Comment: You may want to expand your last sentence because it's fairly vague. (i.e. All four bandwidths for what? 3G has at least five, and there's others for LTE, WiMAX, etc. Do you mean all four *GSM* bands?)

Comment: Yes, the GSM bandwidths. I want to point out in this answer, that _all_ frequencies are easy to find in wikipedia.